# Master/Detail dropdown filtering using Lambda in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'd like to populate a dropdown list based on the selection chosen in the previous field.

Currently I have 2 Lists from my `ViewModel` like so:

```
Manufacturers = context.ManufacturersTable.OrderBy(x => x.ManufacturerName).ToList(),
Models = context.ModelsTable.OrderBy(x => x.ModelName).ToList(),
```

Both lists are populated using a SQL Table with their own data model.

In the `Models` table, I have a column for `ManufacturerID` which matches that of the `ManufacturerID` in the `Manufacturers` table.

I'd like to populate the `Models` list based on the selection of the `Manufacturers` list so that only models associated with the selected manufacturer are displayed.

How would I do this using `Lambda`?

I've been playing with Where and Select but haven't quite been able to get there.

EDIT:

Here's the tables

```
MANUFACTURER   |   MANUFACTURER_ID
Manufacturer 1     GUID1
Manufacturer 2     GUID2

MODEL   |    MODEL_ID    |    MANUFACTURER_ID
Model 1 | GUID1          |    GUID1
Model 2 | GUID2          |    GUID2
Model 3 | GUID3          |    GUID1
Model 4 | GUID4          |    GUID1
```

Comment: We need to see what columns are in both tables.  You need to join the two tables by a common field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
context.ModelsTable.Where(x => x.ManufacturerId == value).OrderBy(x => x.ModelName).ToList()
```

This doesn't work? Pass ManufactureId as `value`. 
`Where` keyword filter data but returns all columns from the table. With `Select` you can select which columns you want to return. You can use these keywords together.

Comment: That's where I was going but getting the value was the problem.

Comment: You should create action in a controller which takes id as an argument and call it from frontend - you can use jQuery to do it. On select event from first dropdown call this new action. I don't understand what is exactly a problem for you. What is your approach - code first or database first?

Comment: Thanks, think I've got it. Got an issue with an Ajax call but I'll do a separate question for that.

Answer (score 1):

When you change the selection of the manufacturer field, call a controller method  with manufacturer id as a parameter that returns:

```
context.ModelsTable
    .Where(x => x.ManufacturerId == manufacturerId)
    .OrderBy(x => x.ModelName)
    .ToList();
```

...then update the select list with the result.